# Find My iPhone Email Notification

Tags: iphone

Is the email notification from Apple that your device has been tracked using Find My iPhone a new feature?

Comment: You can try Apple's 'Friends' app. That does just this, without notifying the other user with emails.

Answer (score 2):

The email feature while using Find My iPhone has been there for a very long time. The email notification feature was silently added as a feature way back in 2011. The email is sent sent when the device reconnects to a network.

There aren't options to turn this feature off.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flurry of the "Find my phone" issues today.

I would assume it is a problem with Apple servers.

I would suggest you [turn the Find my phone off](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702), wait for 1/2 hour and turn it on again (to reset).

Also it might be a bug in the iOS 8.01 so for now just disable it.

Turn off "Find My iPhone" on your phone if you're using the feature. You can do this under Settings > iCloud > Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged into my own phone to find it and received an email 10 minutes later...I think it's something new they are doing and there are probably some bugs to kink out while they do it...hope this helps...I am not concerned on my end anymore and will just wait and see if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

No, I spent over an hour on the phone with apple today. They will notify you every single time you log into find my iphone from now on. It's quite annoying. The guy suggested we all log a complaint at apple.com/feedback to get them to stop the madness.

Answer (score 0):

Update Nov 2015 - El Capitan, iOS 9.1
This no longer appears to happen on each Find my iPhone access - just tested with both my own & my partner's phones - no email.

Comment: Yesterday I used "Find my iPhone" and did receive an email afterward.  But you are right, the email says it is because "A sound was played", not merely because of Find My iPhone access.  El Capitan 10.11.1