# How do I turn off email alerts for find my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to stop receiving alerts every time I sign into find my iPhone. How do I turn off email alerts for find my iPhone?

Comment: Where specifically are you "signing in" to find my iPhone? Are you using a web application on https://icloud.com or some other version of that service?

Answer (score 1):

Update Nov 2015 - El Capitan, iOS 9.1
This no longer appears to happen on each Find my iPhone access - just tested with both my own & my partner's phones - no email.

---

It's not possible. there have been a lot of queries on this recently

See  [Find My iPhone Email Notification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147144/find-my-iphone-email-notification/147149#147149) for more info

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, there is no way to disable Find my iPhone email alerts. I suppose you could set up a filtering rule in your mail client or service to automatically delete or archive the notification, or move it to a folder that's not in your inbox.